# Firebase - Is it possible to use a third party service provider in Firebase Spark Plan

Tags: firebase, react-native, elasticsearch, algolia

Specifically, I need to implement a search in Firebase application and found Algolia and ElasticSearch useful, do I need a Blaze or Flame plan to avail this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be on a payment plan to add services to your app or project.

You only need to be on a payment plan if you wish to automatically mirror your data to another service using Cloud Functions.  If you have another way to integrate the sevice, you do not necessarily need a payment plan.